# Raspberry open Webpage in Background

Tags: html, linux, nodemcu

I have currently installed my NODEMCU with an HTML page on it. Now I want to access it over a public IP via. SSH. I want my Raspberry to call the webbage (10.10.10.99/licht-an).

Now my problem is that I don't want to open a webbrowser all the time. Can anyone provide some ideas?

Comment: Try `wget` or `curl`.

Comment: Thanks! This worked:xxx@Chaos-VM:~$ curl --head 10.10.10.99/light2on
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:
jfk@Chaos-VM:~$ curl --head 10.10.10.99/light2on

---

Response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html